# El mayor numero

Tags: javascript

hola buenas noches estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que debo indicar a traves de un formulario 3 numeros y estos pasarlos a un script que los compare y me diga mediante un alert cual es el mayor de los 3, este es el codigo que tengo yo pero no funciona.Como debo pasarle los campos del formulario correctamente al script? Gracias!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>mayor numero</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="view-port" content="width:device-with;initial-scale:1,0">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num3" id="num3" required><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="numMayor(num1,num2,num3);"name="numMayor" value="Aceptar">
    </form>
    <script>
        function numMayor(num1,num2,num3){
            if(num1>num2){
                alert("num1 es mayor que num2");
            }
            else if(num2>num1){
                alert("num2 es mayor que num1");
            }
            else if(num2>num3){
                alert("num2 es mayor que num3");
            }
            else if (num1>num3){
                alert("num1 es mayor que num3");
            }
            else{
                alert("num3 es mayor que num1");    
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes apoyarte de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max y con eso encontrar el mayor

Comment: Muchas gracias!! el problema también reside en que me marea un poco pasarle los parametros a la funcion desde html, acabo de empezar con el javascript y no tengo mucha idea de hacer esto, nose si lo estoy haciendo correctamente y que es lo que estoy realizando mal en mi codigo para que no funcione.

Comment: Yo haría esto: escuchar el click del botón, obtener el value de los tres inputs y agregarlos a un array, finalmente usar la función que te digo y posterior imprimir el valor mayor obtenido

Comment: me podrías explicar un poco mejor? como le paso los parametros correctamente desde el html a la funcion ?

Comment: gracias :) ando super perdida, nose muy bien como funciona jeje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indicas que el ejercicio es sobre encontrar el número mayor de los 3, pero yo veo que evalúas en parejas, lo cual no me deja en claro si será efectivo al momento de determinar el número mas grande.

Considera si estuvieras evaluando: 1, 11, 21

La estructura de if else me parece no cubre lo esperado.

Entonces considero puedes:

- Obtener en variables los siguientes elementos:

  - Botón del formulario
  - los 3 inputs donde se reciben números
  - Declaramos un vector donde almacenaremos los números
- En el evento click del botón

  - Agregamos los 3 valores numéricos tecleados en los inputs al vector
  - Usamos la función [Math.max.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max) para encontrar el número mayor
- Imprimimos el número mayor

Código:

```html
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num3" id="num3" required><br>
        <input id="botonEvaluador" type="submit" name="numMayor" value="Aceptar">
    </form>
    <script>
        let botonEvaluador = document.getElementById('botonEvaluador');
        let num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
        let num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
        let num3 = document.getElementById('num3');
        let numeros = [];
      
        botonEvaluador.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          numeros.push(num1.value, num2.value, num3.value);
          alert(Math.max.apply(null, numeros));
        });
    </script>
```

O bien puedes continuar con la estructura de condicionales pero: evaluar al menos a 2 de los 3 números para verificar que sean mayores que los otros 2 restantes es decir:

```html
    <form>
            <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" required><br>
            <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" required><br>
            <input type="number" name="num3" id="num3" required><br>
            <input id="botonEvaluador" type="submit" name="numMayor" value="Aceptar">
        </form>
        <script>
            let botonEvaluador = document.getElementById('botonEvaluador');
            let num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
            let num2 = document.getElementById('num2');
            let num3 = document.getElementById('num3');
          
            botonEvaluador.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              if (parseInt(num1.value) > parseInt(num2.value) && parseInt(num1.value) > parseInt(num2.value)) {
                console.log('el mayor es :'+num1.value);
              } else if(parseInt(num2.value) > parseInt(num1.value) && parseInt(num2.value) > parseInt(num3.value)) {
                console.log('el mayor es :'+num2.value);
              } else {
                 console.log('el mayor es :'+num3.value);
              }
            });
        </script>
```

De esta forma te aseguras que cuando indiques que el número 1 es mayor es por que lo comparaste tanto contra el número 2 cómo el número 3 y lo mismo para el número 2, si ninguna de las 2 condiciones anteriores se cumplen quiere decir que el número3 es el mayor de todos, de aqui ya puedes continuar avanzand para buscar mejoras a este código, recomiendo leer sobre [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt)

Comment: Como siempre muy buena respuesta (+1). No se si notaste que el problema de OP es que **no sabe que necesita anular el comportamiento por defecto del botón** para que el formulario no sea enviado y lo haces con `event.preventDefault()` y que para poder hacerlo pasas el objeto event al manejador. De modo que, me parece, sería importante destacar el hecho.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!! Finalmente me hice una idea y logre hacerlo por mi misma aunque aún hay alguna duda que me queda pendiente, me marea un poco el hecho de saber cuando le estoy pasando los parametros desde el html correctamente.

Comment: El primer snippet tiene un error y es que nunca se blanquea el arreglo `numeros`. Lo más simple sería crear un arreglo con los valores y obtener el `max` en este cada vez que se toca el botón.

Comment: @azucarilla en ese caso te invito a qué publiques tu respuesta y sea esa la aceptada, quevedo tienes mucha razón aquí puede leer más   https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault y es cierto Marcos lo que mencionas, ya le dejo a la op profundice más investigando pero es totalmente cierto lo que mencionas

Comment: @azucarilla personalmente no me gusta la idea de mezclar js en el html por eso maneje todo por separado en un script, al menos a mí se me complica seguirle la pista cuando veo JS dentro de tags HTML

Answer (score 1):

El error es que esta mostrando el resultado directamente sin aun recorrer todos los números, la solución es almacenar en una variable para contener el mayor eje: `contiene_mayor` , luego si `contiene_mayor`  es menor al siguiente numero a comparar entonces reemplaza su valor. Al final `contiene_mayor` contendrá el numero mayor :D.

```js
let uno = 20;
let dos = 35;
let tres = 40;

let contiene_mayor = uno;

if(contiene_mayor < uno){
   contiene_mayor = uno;
}
if(contiene_mayor < dos){
   contiene_mayor = dos;
}
if(contiene_mayor < tres){
   contiene_mayor = tres;
} 

alert("El mayor es "+contiene_mayor )
```

Ahora para tu caso estas pasando en `onclick="numMayor(...)` a `num1`,`num2`,`num3` pero estos son elementos HTML así que para saber su valor debes usar [`num1.value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)  y para saber el nombre `num1.name`, tu código se vería así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>mayor numero</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="view-port" content="width:device-with;initial-scale:1,0">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num3" id="num3" required><br>
        <button onclick="numMayor(num1,num2,num3);" >Aceptar</button>
    </form>
    <script>
function numMayor(num1,num2,num3){
  // para almacenar el numero y el nombre del mayor
  let mayor = num1;
  
  // valido el mayor
  if(mayor.value < num1.value){
    mayor = num1;
  }
  if(mayor.value < num2.value){
    mayor = num2;
  }
  if(mayor.value < num3.value){
    mayor = num3;
  }
  // muestro el resultado
  alert('El numero mayor en '+mayor.value+' en '+ mayor.name)
}
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cambie `<input type="submit">` por un `<button>` dado que el `type="submit"` hará que se recargue la pagina por lo tanto la función `numMayor` no se ejecutará.

### Extra

Como un extra si deseas ordenar varios valores debes ahora usar [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) para almacenar los valores y luego trabajar con ellos.

```js
let a = 20;
let b = 40;
let c = 10;

// guardo valores
let valores = [a,b,c]

// metodo para ordenar
valores.sort(function(i, j) {
  return i - j;
});

console.log(valores)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
           function numMayor(){
                var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value) //Obtenemos los valores de los input
                var num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value) //Obtenemos los valores de los input
                var num3 = Number(document.getElementById('num3').value) //Obtenemos los valores de los input
                    if(num1>num2){ //Comparamos los valores
                        console.log("num1 es mayor que num2");
                    }
                    else if(num2 > num1){
                       console.log("num2 es mayor que num1");
                    }
                    else if(num2 > num3){
                        console.log("num2 es mayor que num3");
                    }
                    else if (num1 > num3){
                        console.log("num1 es mayor que num3");
                    }
                    else{
                       console.log("num3 es mayor que num1");    
                    }
                }
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>mayor numero</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <meta name="view-port" content="width:device-with;initial-scale:1,0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="number"  id="num1" required><br>
                <input type="number"  id="num2" required><br>
                <input type="number"  id="num3" required><br>
                <input type="submit" onclick="numMayor()"  value="Aceptar">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

No habías cerrado Comillas y tenías errores de paréntesis

Comment: hola!! he estado probando el codigo y viendo los fallos, el ultimo else no funcionaba bien por lo que he añadido un else if con la comparación de num3 > num1, ahora no me saca ningun tipo ventana, no funciona, otra duda que tenia es como funciona exactamente esto "var num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value)"

Comment: Vos cuando agarrás el valor del input la computadora lo toma como un String (como si fuese texto). Lo que tenes que hacer es pasarlo a número con el `Number()` Así se interpreta como tal. Aparte del método `Number()`, tenes otros como `parseInt()` o `parseFloat()`. Si te sirvio la rta no olvides marcarla como favorita y útil :).

Comment: Gracias por el aporte Vencho. Es muy importante agregar comentarios y explicaciones al uso del código. El objetivo final de ayudar es que quienes consultan puedan aprender de las respuestas. Si sólo copian y pegan para resolver sus problemas es poco lo que se logra a cambio del trabajo de quienes responden.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar de esta manera

Declarar una variable mayor que es la que te va a indicar cual es el mayor de los 3 números a través de una comparación, asignando primeramente num1 como el mayor y luego comparando y asignando con los demás números…

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>mayor numero</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="view-port" content="width:device-with;initial-scale:1,0">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2" required><br>
        <input type="number" name="num3" id="num3" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" onclick="numMayor()" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function numMayor() {
            var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
            var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
            var num3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num3').value);
            var mayor = 0;
            mayor = num1;

            if (num2 > mayor) {
                mayor = num2;
            }
            if (num3 > mayor) {
                mayor = num3;
            }
            alert("El numero mayor es " + mayor);
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            num3 = 0;
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad